# Execute the JS first then go to 'page.php on <a>

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<script>
 function delete(){
       .
       .
 }
</script>

<a href='page.php' onClick="delete()">Delete</a>
```

I would like to execute the JS first, then go to 'page.php'. Just wondering if it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

In `delete` function add in the end:

```
function delete(a){
    // ...
    window.location = a.href;
}
```

And call this function with:

```
<a href='page.php' onClick="delete(this)">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use delete() for name of the function. Its a keyword in javascript that's why the function didn't works. Then use the return while call the function,it causes first executes js then go to 'page.php'.

```
<a href='page.php' onclick="return fundelete();">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You cannot call a function "delete", because it's a private keyword. Use delteItem instead.

The function delete will be called always before browser redirect. You can have some problem in case of asynchronous call inside delete function. So, place a "return false" on anchor onclick for disable link and place a redirect inside function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteItem(el){
   // ... some code
   // and when you finish
   window.location.href = el.href; 
}
</script>

<a href='page.php' onclick="deleteItem(this); return false;">Delete</a>
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

DOnt use predefine keyword its may dump the Coding here is the Eg:

i used delete function , // it does not work  because it predefined,

```
<a href="index2.php" onclick="delete(event)">clickuuu mee</a>
<script>

    function delete(e){
       alert("+++++++++++++++++++++++");
        // e.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
```

Here i used delete1 it work,

```
<a href="index2.php" onclick="delete1(event)">clickuuu mee</a>
<script>
    function delete1(e){
       alert("+++++++++++++++++++++++");
        //e.preventDefault();
        //window.location = a.href;
        //return false;
    }
</script>
```

make it clear,